# FABridge on shopping cart checkout

Tags: apache-flex

I’m working with a team to put together a repeatable checkout process.

We are using a Flex shopping cart and then opening up an IFrame using flexiframe to capitalize on our ASP.net secure checkout server.  This works like a charm until we click on a simple button in ASP.net that does one thing - and one thing only.  It’s supposed to trigger a process, using FABridge, to get us back to the first ‘page’ in the Flex application so as to run another transaction.A few things I have done, and please let me know if you need more data, code, or whatever.

I put FABridge.js in the Flex project’s html-template folder.
I put FABridge.as in the a ‘bridge’ package in the Flex project.

I put FABridge.js in the ASP.net project.
I declare this file on the aspx page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/FABridge.js"></script>
```

Then, I declared the ASP.net button like so:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNewOrder" Text="Place New Order" OnClientClick="newOrder();"/>
```

The newOrder function is written like so:

function newOrder() {
            var flexApp = FABridge('AdminTrak', 'flex');
            flexApp.setPage(0);
        }

The setPage function in Flex looks like so:

```
public function setPage(pageNum:int):void {
            model.pageSetter(pageNum, 2)
        }
```

Now, I added a namespace on the view where this function resides like so:

```
xmlns:bridge="bridge.*" as well as the following declaration:

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <bridge:FABridge bridgeName="flex" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

Also, I added the following line in my index.template.html file:

```
flashvars.bridgeName = "flex";
```

So, I run a transaction and then click on the button to place a new order.  All I get is an error that tells me that FABridge.flex is not defined.

Please help.

Comment: what happens when you change this:
 var flexApp = FABridge('AdminTrak', 'flex');

to this:
 var flexApp = FABridge.flex.root();

(not that i use FABridge, but this looked like the major difference between your code and the example i found on the world domain.)

Comment: That is what we started with.  Doesn't work at all.