# Flex-IFrame Comm Test Not Working

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to get the IFrameCommTest example ([from the Flex-IFrame site](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/)) to work in Flex 4, and, while the IFrame itself works, the communication does not.  In particular, I need to get the included HTML page to call functions from the flex app (I already have a way to get the Flex app to talk to the HTML).

I've [exported the project](http://www.mediafire.com/file/172448jkkgva4ki/iframeCommTest.fxp) to facilitate your help.

The problem, I suspect, is that the "parent.FABridge" doesn't exist. My guess is that something in flex4 changed with regard to how things are located in the DOM.

(This post is related to the earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567931/fabridge-problem-please-help) about FABridge.

I thought this would be a clearer example of the problem. )

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this my own self :D

The difference over the mechanism above is in the getFlexApp() function, and it provides a way to, well, get the flex object.  Once the objecty it gotten, I just call the EIButtonClicked() function, and pass a value to it.

```
function getFlexApp(appName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf ("Microsoft") !=-1) {
        return window.top[appName];
    } else {
        return window.top.document[appName];
    }
}

function callFlexFunction() { 
    var sTxt ;
    sTxt  = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    alert('HTML/Javascript wants to tell you about ' + sTxt);
    getFlexApp('iframeCommTest').EIButtonClicked(sTxt) ;
}
```

Meanwhile, the flex side has an external interface callback established.  You can see that the "EIButtonClicked" referenced in the JS above is matched by the label for the callback in the AS below.

```
/**
* When the button is clicked.
*/
public function onEIButtonClicked(data:String):void {
  Alert.show("Flash wants to tell you about " + data);
}


protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler():void {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (ExternalInterface.available) { 
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("EIButtonClicked", onEIButtonClicked); 
  } 
}
```